# How do I match every number in a string, that does not appear after a letter?

Tags: regex, adobe

I'm trying to write a regex that matches all numbers until the first occurrence of a letter or, to put it another way, matches any numbers not preceded by a letter.

```
"1 & 2 Are numbers"             // Matches "1" and "2"
"3 Is a number smaller than 4"  // Matches "3"
```

I would have thought that something like the following would work, but to no avail:

```
(?<![A-Z])\d
```

This will be for use in Adobe InDesign, which has pretty good regex support, as far as I can tell.

Comment: It is `(?<![a-zA-Z].*)\d+` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/yfeWke/1)), but I am not sure it will work there.

Comment: Strictly speaking, your second example should also match 4 since it is not preceded by a letter but the 32nd ASCII character `space`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yeah that works in Regexr, but sadly not InDesign, although it does give me something to try and build on.

Comment: @GaëtanBoyals To clarify: I mean preceding letters as opposed to _immediately_ preceding.

Comment: Then you must admit the regex support is not that "pretty" in Adobe InDesign. :(

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pattern which finds all numbers in a line up to the first letter `[a-zA-Z]`.
It finds 1, 2 and 3 in your test strings, but not 4.

```
^((?![a-zA-Z])[\s\S])*[0-9]+
```

Comment: This will work in many places, but not InDesign, sadly